# Where are my sharepoint credentials stored in windows and how do I delete them?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, sharepoint, credentials

I have opened a word file from my online Sharepoint account (office 365) on my local computer using office 2007 word.
Now I have the file listed in the "Recent Documents" list in word, and I can open it directly from word without using a browser.
Now I want to **sign-out**, so that the document will not open when I try to open it from word. Here's what I tried:

- I have used my browser to sign out of my office 365 account.
- I cleared my entire browsing history (including cookies).
- I checked the windows credential manager to see that there are no stored
  credentials for my Sharepoint account.
- I ran "net use" to see there is no mounted Sharepoint folder.

However, I can still open the file from word.

Somewhere on my computer my Sharepoint credentials are stored, and word is using them to open that file - where are they and how do I delete them?

I'm using office 2007 on windows 8 (64bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out unmounting the Sharepoint folder using `net use /delete` was enough, but to make it stick I had to **restart the `WebClient` windows service**.
I guess the service had in its memory my credentials or maybe just the authentication cookies.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The Word document is probably a locally cached version of the document.  If you were to open it and make changes and try to check them in to SharePoint, you'd have to sign in again.  Did you try locating the local copy of the document and deleting it?  I'd bet it's in a temp folder somewhere.  If you really want to remove access to it, right-click on the document in your Recent Documents list and see where the Target is, and delete it from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but word was actually accessing the online version, I checked using [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) that it had connected to `sharepoint.com` every time I opened the document. I figured it out eventually, see my answer.